# Hide / Show Specific Table Rows

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to be able to hide on default specific rows within a table.

Basically this is a "My Basket" page within a e-commerce site and the idea here is to be able to show all instances of more than one of the same product.

Example: Say you choose in quantity to have 3 goats - underneath the product displayed there is a link which says "Show all instances". What this means is to show each instance of the total 3 goats you want if you were to click on the anchor.

Here is an image of what I'm doing / trying to achieve:

[image]

So, the issue I'm having is how to structurally put the "show all instances" rows together in the HTML. Create another table underneath the parent row? I thought this and came into the issue of how to position the "instances" with the correct product.

Here is my HTML code so far - this code just shows what I have done to achieve each product row:

```
<div class="item-section">
        <span class="section-heading">Smiles Gifts</span>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #666666;padding: 0 0 5px 0;" >
            <tr>
                <th class="col-1">&nbsp;</th>
                <th class="col-2">Qty</th>
                <th class="col-3">Frequency</th>
                <th class="col-4">Card Type</th>
                <th class="col-5">Edit/Remove</th>
                <th class="col-6">Subtotal</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td class="item col-1 clearfix">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src="images/cart_dummy_image.jpg" alt="" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="product">World Food Programme</span>
                                <!-- LINK TO SHOW OTHER INSTANCES -->
                                <a class="show-instances" href="#">Show all instances</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td class="col-2"">1</td>
                <td class="col-3">One Off</td>
                <td class="col-4">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="col-5">
                    <a href="#" class="blue-anchor">Edit</a>
                    <a href="#">Remove</a>
                </td>
                <td class="col-6">$45.00</td>
            </tr>
</div>
```

Hopefully the information provided is detailed enough but if not let me know any questions and I will do my best to assist!

Comment: add more details in the html code where you want to put the button to toggle the rows. The idea is just setting all the rows which has the same product with the class equals to the id of the products. Then when you click on the toggle button, use $('.id1').toggle();

Comment: _"So, the issue I'm having is how to structurally put the "show all instances" rows together in the HTML."_ - So are you asking about the html structure, or about how to use jQuery to do the hiding and showing? (Or both?)

Comment: Mainly the HTML structure - the jquery if you can help that would be great.

Comment: @ThaiTran updated with HTML Comments for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `HTML` simply add more rows for each entry, then you need to do some tweaks in java-script to hide and show those rows. I would prefer [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) because it handles `DOM` elegantly.

Here simple way to accomplish your task, (*only posting javascript*)

```
var link = $('<a class="show-instances" href="#">Show all instances</a>');
$('tr.main').hide().first().find('.product').parent().remove('a').append(link);
$('tr.main').first().show();

$('table').on('click', 'a.show-instances', function() {
    var selectedClass = $(this).closest('tr.main').attr('class').split(' ');
    $('.' + selectedClass[1]).not(':has("a.show-instances")').toggle();
    return false;
});​
```

Look at the working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thujeevan/HSDXd/)**

Comment: thanks a heap for this man! Only question I have for you now is how to make the "show-instances" slide down instead of show? I tried replacing .toggle with .slideToggle but didn't quite work. Suggestions?

Comment: @Filth ok, it is the matter of block level elements, try [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thujeevan/HSDXd/3/). But you need to work on the alignments.